# Whipped cream from milk powder

Tags: cream, whipped-cream

Recently I saw a video that shows powdered milk can be whipped with cold water to make topping for cakes.

I did a research on Google and yes, some articles/blogs said that it can be whipped. I actually tried myself using half and half powdered milk and whipped it with a hand mixer but it didn’t work, running like normal milk. 
So I suppose not any type of milk works. Anyone has idea about that? I’d appreciate very much.

P.S.: Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 3):

There are methods that whip very cold (up to semi-frozen) low-to-no-fat UHT milk to a whipped cream consistency using an immersion blender with the whipping disk. The key factors are temperature and fat content, for both, the lower the better.

I would not recommend using this product for a cake, because the stability is quite limited<sup>1</sup>. Topping a dessert and serving it immediately is fine, any kind storage is not.

I would expect that a non-fat milk powder in cold water works just as well and I vaguely remember my mom doing something along that line a few decades ago.

---

<sup>1</sup> Some sources suggest adding instant gelatine powder for stabilization, but as I have never tried it, I can’t confirm how well it works.

Answer (score 2):

Whipped cream is a fat-based foam which forms when the tiny fat globules in cream coalesce. For this to happen, the lowest needed proportion of fat is 30%, but more is better. If you want to have a powdered product with which to make whipped cream, you have to buy powdered cream. Whipped milk won't work for that.

Milk can also create protein-based foams, as mentioned in Stephie's answer. They don't behave like whipped cream though. I don't know how feasible is to make them from powdered milk, and what the exact process will be - after your comment, this is likely to be what you are seeing. To get it, you would indeed have to use the exact process they are suggesting, with the proper amount of fat, and you will still not end up with whipped cream.

Comment: No, they used non-fat dry milk. I actually found the link of the product : https://www.walmart.com/ip/Great-Value-Instant-Nonfat-Dry-Milk-25-6-oz/10415722. There’s even a recipe of creamy whipped topping at the back of the bag. Unfortunately I can’t find that brand where I live

Comment: I expanded the answer to be more informative and to cover foams which are not whipped cream.

Comment: I know with the amount of fat (non fat actually) in dry milk, we can’t never obtain something that is as fat as cream. So I should have called them whipped topping instead of whipped cream to avoid confusion. The idea in my question is to make something that can substitue whipped cream to cover the cake and is not fat with just one ingredient. Indeed, I saw one youtuber used that whipped milk to decorate the cake.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the problem lays in what you understand as "whipped cream". First, yes you can beat the powdered milk to creamy consistency. The caveat - it's cream not Whipped cream.

Even making whipped cream from milk would require to churn the milk into cream (so beat out a lot of water and leave 30% fat content) and then WHIPPING the result.

Here are few things you can try:

- Make half a cup of milk from powdered milk. Boil with 1/5 cup of sugar and vanilla sugar. Let to cool. Meanwhile beat/whipp 1/8 of a cup of soft margerine (or butter) until it get fluffy. Combine with cooled milk. At the end add 2 cups of powdered milk.
- Make milk from powder with very cold water (even ice cubes if you have blender). Freeze that.  Mix Caseine and flavour of your choosing (if vanilla don't add vanila extract but vanilla sugar). Add xanthan or guar AND gelatine (you can use powdered puddings or protein ice cream powders). Put in blender/mix and mix for 20 minutes (or until creamy consistency).

YOu can make it more "whipped" but that require freezing the rezult and then whipping with very areating tool. And it stay whipped for a short time as it get warmer.

Comment: Whipped _milk_ into a _whipped cream_ consistency is possible and often described as something like “diet cream”. Lots of “dieting communities” are sharing recipes like that.

Comment: @Stephie I had in mind only milk. So without any addtion of gelatin or xanthan. So even if somoene is whipping it from milk they are really turning milk into cream (I assume one of the steps is removing extra water).

Comment: Please see my answer, no removal of water necessary. It works without stabilizer, but will keep only for something between ten and thirty minutes. Speaking from experience.